# How to create and return Predicate<T> from withing Nashorn engine java 8

Tags: java-8, predicate, nashorn, javascript-engine

How to create a Predicate from ScriptEngine in java 8 and return it to java program?

Predicate conditions are operators and their comparing values and are good in number. So I wanted to get the predicate from javaScript Engine something like below:

```
public Predicate<Object> getPredicate(String operator, String value) {
return Predicate<Object> engine.eval("(i)-> i" + operator + value);
}
```

here operator can be >=, <=,>,< etc.
this is just a simpler version of the actual problem. How can i create predicates from nashorn, i'll be able drive after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
engine.eval("new java.util.function.Predicate(function(i) { return i" + operator + value + ";})");
```

Also, I think in your original post you didn't want to quote `"value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think about something like this:

```
public Predicate<Object> getPredicate(final String operator, final String value) {
  return i -> {
    Bindings bindings = new Bindings();
    bin.put("i", i);
    bin.put("value", value);
    return engine.eval("i " + operator + " value", bindings);
  };
}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot instantiate the type Bindings" for new Bindings()